# Custom Login Page for Spring Security Configuration (passing request attributes)

Tags: spring-security, annotations

In my application, user lands on the landing page with the buttons Apply and Login.

On Both button clicks , user is shown custom login page by Spring security and if authentication is successful the user is sent to application page or dashboard page based on whether they clicked on apply or login pages.

Now on my custom login page, I added a Register button which when clicked open the registration page with a registration form. Now how can I send a request attribute from the landing page through the spring security login page and then the registration page so that when user completes registration they are sent either to the application page or dashboard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the authentication as true once user completes the registration, I hope rest of your configuration will take care of flow to dashboard or applicaiton page otherwise you will need to configure required things when user completes his/her registration and route him to required view as per your needs.

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().setAuthenticated(true);